# What is the best Linux distribution for Vmware server?

Tags: linux

In terms of Webserver and low package size installation.

Comment: You probably want to rephrase your question. ;)

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, the best distro for VMWare is the one the admin has the most experience with.  With the GUI stuff all disabled I've not found any difference in performance between RedHat, Centos and Ubuntu when running VMWare.

Picking the distro that you can adminster easiest will save you hassle.  If you already have a few linux systems using the same flavour makes the admins job a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me if you are asking about the distro for the Vmware host, or for the guest operating system that will be your web server.

I generally really like Debian or Debian based distributions.  But as far as Vmware is concerned Centos or anything really should work.

If you are looking at setting up many vms on this server you might want to look at using the bare-metal hypervisor product that has been released as a free product. (Vmware ESX)